# Update mysql rows with value extracted from counting another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following query:

```
SELECT int_intrebari.id, COUNT( id_raspuns ) AS nr_raspunsuri
FROM int_intrebari, int_raspunsuri
WHERE int_intrebari.id = int_raspunsuri.id
GROUP BY id
```

Is it possible to update first table with nr_raspunsuri from the query, without writing a foreach statement?

Comment: Which column do you want to update?

Comment: int_intrebari I want to be updated with the count from the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) with `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE int_intrebari i1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, COUNT( id_raspuns ) AS nr_raspunsuri
    FROM int_intrebari
    GROUP BY id 
) i2 ON i1.id = i2.id
SET i1.nr_raspunsuri = i2.nr_raspunsuri
```

Comment: Can you provide link which confirms this as valid syntax? Because [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) suggests this syntax should cause an error.

Comment: @Vyktor This is the correct syntax. Look at [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a426a7/1)

Comment: @Vyktor - The `UPDATE` syntax in the manual suggests that the table references comes after  the `UPDATE` clause directly `UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference ...`, so it should be `UPDATE nt_intrebari i1 INNER JOIN ...` where `nt_intrebari i1 INNER JOIN ...` is the tables references. This how I understand it.

Comment: +1 now, I've already found that [`table_reference`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) can be quite complex expression, but I could have sworn that you had `FROM` instead of `INNER JOIN` in your answer before...

Comment: @Vyktor Yes. I too see that syntax before and then Mahmoud Gamal updated it to correct.

Comment: @Vyktor - Yes the first syntax was invalid. It was the MS SQL Server syntax. Sorry for that, I am always be confused between the MS-SQL Server syntax and the MySQL syntax,

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like -

```
update int_intrebari left join int_raspunsuri on int_intrebari.id =int_raspunsuri.id
set int_intrebari.column_to_update = int_raspunsuri.column_from_update_second_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
  (SELECT int_intrebari.id, COUNT( id_raspuns) AS nr_raspunsuri
   FROM int_intrebari, int_raspunsuri
   WHERE int_intrebari.id = int_raspunsuri.id
   GROUP BY id) t1,
  int_raspunsuri t2
SET
  t2.nr_raspunsuri=t1.nr_raspunsuri
WHERE
  t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: I dont understand how it will be a hard time as mysql is case-insensitive by default for all keywords